Test the difference in difference with Completely Between-subject Design
The usual DID has two groups which is between-subject, however, the subjects in each group go through both the pre-treatment and post-treatment which is within-subject. In my dataset, I have four groups going through each cases independently, thus, a completely between-subject design. Let me illustrate it with the following MWE.
library(dplyr)

Subject <- c(1:40) 

A1 <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 30))
A2 <- c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10), rep(0, 20))
B1 <- c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 10), rep(0, 10))
B2 <- c(rep(0, 30), rep(1, 10))

Y <- c(rnorm(n = 10, mean = 5, sd = 1),
       rnorm(n = 10, mean = 10, sd = 1),
       rnorm(n = 10, mean = 20, sd = 1),
       rnorm(n = 10, mean = 50, sd = 1))

df <- bind_cols(ID = Subject, A1 = A1, A2 = A2, 
                B1 = B1, B2 = B2, Y = Y)

A1, A2, B1, B2 are treatment dummies. I use feols to run a simple regression since I want to include a time/period fixed effect and cluter the se at the group level (for the ease of illustration, I did not include the period and group variable in the example). In the regression, I use all the dummy variables (and other controls) as independent variables.
I know that I can use a Wald test to know whether the difference between A1 and A2 is significant. However, what I would like to know as well is whether the difference in difference (B2 - B1) - (A2 - A1) is significant or not.
A colleague told me that one can simply write test((B2 - B1) - (A2 - A1)) in stata to get the result. However, how can I do it in R?
Thanks for any help and comments!
